# Infinitely Many Touching Circles - Can This Exist?

Tags: geometry, circles

Recently, I learned about the "Problem of Apollonius" in which three circles are drawn, and the task is to draw a fourth circle that is tangential to these three circles (it seems that if you "fix" these first three circles, there are many options for the fourth circle): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius

I was thinking about a "Generalized" version of this problem - if you were to first draw "n" number of circles, could we then determine if a circle exists that is tangential to all of these "n" circles?

I tried to read about this online and came across the following links:

- " A Theorem on Circle Configurations " : https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0706/0706.0372.pdf (Linked in a previous question I posted)
- "Generalized Problem of Apollonius": https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.03090

However, I was not able to fully comprehend these links because my understanding of mathematics is insufficient .

Thus - can someone please help me understand: if you were to first draw "n" number of circles, could we then determine if a circle exists that is tangential to all of these "n" circles? Does the Problem of Apollonius extend to "infinitely touching circles" - or even in higher dimensions to "spheres" and "hyperspheres"?

Thanks!

Comment: I might be completely wrong but from the wiki page you linked, it says that there is 0-8 solutions to finding a circle tangent to 3 given one, so pick 3 from your n circles, find the tangent circle solution(s) and check if its tangent with the others?

Answer (score 1):

No, unless you get lucky.

Your problem is similar to asking, if I choose 3 points, does there exist a line through them? Of course you can choose 3 points on a line, but in general, 3 points form a triangle not a line.

Similarly, if you have 3 circles, you can usually choose a circle (or depending on which of the three you want inside your circle 0-8 circles) that’s tangent to them. However, if you add a fourth circle, unless you choose it very specially, chances are that it won’t be tangent to any of the up to 8 circles that previously worked and so you get no solutions.

Comment: If I understand the question right, it asks about a case where this is possible. If I interprete the answer correctly, such cases actually exist.